# Autodesk Forge translation missing part files from standard library

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a case where assembly translation fails because it is missing parts. However, these parts are from internal SolidWorks libraries.

For example, the assembly translation reports errors of cannot find "instrument ball bearing_68_am.sldprt", "hex nut style 1_am.sldprt", "pan slot head_am (threaded).SLDPRT". These are not user files, but are SolidWorks parts from the standard material libraries, so SolidWorks finds these files from its own folders, not from my project’s folders. These are standard screws and nuts.

This does not seem like an Autodesk problem, however it is a problem I am facing as a user of this Autodesk service. What is the recommended solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi sabrehagen, So, your assembly has some standard parts of Solidworks. When Forge service tries to translate, it cannot find the parts because no Solidworks library on the cloud, so it tries to look for in your folder structure, but obviously because it is a library part, there is not a copy in the local folder, then the translation failed. Is my understanding correct?
 I have not such experience, even how Forge handles standard parts of Inventor.. I will need to test with Inventor firstly.

Comment: Hi Xiaodong, yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: With my test, the behavior of Inventor is same, Forge does not translate the standard part. I am checking with engineer team on what we missed, or it is current design.

Comment: Thank you Xiaodong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been discussing with our engineer team, regarding with the behavior. Finally, I got to know with Pack & Go of Inventor，  it can indeed work with the part of Content Center. While the truth is, Pack & Go packs the CC part, so Forge extractor on the cloud can find it and build the hierarchy. The only difference to custom part is: the relative folder of CC part is specific.

In addition, our engineer team has confirmed current extractor on the cloud cannot automatically download missing CC part. So the only way is either using Pack & Go, then specifying the root file, or providing the CC part explicitly (as a custom part).

I saw the similar way (Pack & Go) with Solidworks:
http://help.solidworks.com/2017/english/solidworks/sldworks/c_pack_and_go.htm
probably it could also work in this case.